# Docker running inside a USB Flash Drive

Tags: shell, docker, usb-drive, usb-device

How can I run a Docker Image inside a USB Flash Drive to use in a Linux Computer without Docker installed?

To avoid Installing in Each Linux Computer, I just need to use docker inside the USB Flash Drive, to use Images I create or Working with programs inside my OS images.

I've Looking for a while for this, but I only Find this Question without awnser:

https://forums.docker.com/t/can-i-run-my-docker-container-from-flash-drive/32393

Comment: This seems to attend your necessities https://github.com/jrruethe/debian-micro

Comment: "The only dependency is that Docker needs to be available on the build machine." Docker is not available on the machine

Comment: Well you need to make the iso and have one working version of docker

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1418564/creating-a-portable-docker). It basically comes down to manually installing docker on your external drive by downloading the binaries and creating an start script that specifies the path of the images using the `--data-root`  parameter of dockerd. You cannot / should not do this with a ntfs or fat32 file system, however. I managed to run a portable docker instance from an external harddrive with a xfs partition.

```
#/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:$(pwd):$(pwd)/compose
$(pwd)/dockerd --data-root $(pwd)/../data/
pid=$(cat /var/run/docker.pid)
kill -9 $pid
```